# When the RS232 call is canceled, which pin transmits it to the DTE?

Tags: communication, rs232, pins

According to my research: When the call to DCE in the RS232 protocol arrives at  the ring indicator (9) pin is activated and information is sent to the DTE. Let's say we talked for a while and we had to decommission the call. But which pin or pins transmit this information when the call is decommissioned? I can't find the answer to this question. Could you help me out please ? Thank you so much.

Comment: For very clear and comprehensive coverage on this topic you should get the book, *"Technical Aspects of Data Communication"* by John McNamara. I think the 1988 edition was his last one. There is very little to be had that is nearly as good as this book on the topic you are asking about. It is very ***comprehensive***. And it *will* answer your questions. Everything else since his book is junk, by comparison (my opinion.)

Comment: RS232 does not define signalling protocols. It's a hardware specification.

Comment: @Andyaka Actually the RS-232 standard does define how the Control Circuits (handshake signals) relate to data transmission.

Comment: I feel like I'm in a time warp. Just today a colleague at work asked me about an FTP client, and now someone is trying to use _all_ of RS-232!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RS-232 handshaking suffers from a number of things:

1. It's complex
2. There are very few real RS-232 DCE devices any more.
3. It's very frequently not fully, or not properly, implemented.
4. There is enormous scope for variations.

The answer to your question is:

**The call terminates when any of DCD, DSR or DTR are de-asserted.**

- Caller or called PC will drop DTR if it wants to hang up.
- Each DCD will drop if the call fails at the telephone exchange
- Either DSR will drop if the modem fails.

**If one side wants to hang up, it drops DTR.  The other side will see DCD drop.**

DCD can drop (can't hear other modem) *without* DSR dropping (still off-hook ready for data).  Normally a DTE gives it a timeout (perhaps 5 seconds) to see if it's a temporary noise problem, but if it continues, the DTE de-asserts DTR to tell the local DCE to hang up.

Here's a description of one implementation of the full process, from [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/8/83.html):

> Perhaps the best way to understand how these signals interact is to examine a step-by-step example of a modem interfacing with a PC. The following steps describe a transaction in which a remote modem calls a local modem.
>
> 1. The local PC uses software to monitor the RI (Ring Indicate) signal.
> 2. When the remote modem wants to communicate with the local modem, it generates an RI signal. [*In reality the calling PC sends AT commands to tell the modem to initiate the call.*] This signal is transferred by the local modem to the local PC.
> 3. The local PC responds to the RI signal by asserting the DTR (Data Terminal Ready) signal when it is ready to communicate.
> 4. After recognizing the asserted DTR signal, the modem responds by asserting DSR (Data Set Ready) after it is connected to the communications line. DSR indicates to the PC that the modem is ready to exchange further control signals with the DTE to commence communication. When DSR is asserted, the PC begins monitoring DCD for an indication that data is being sent over the communication line.
> 5. The modem asserts DCD (Data Carrier Detect) after it has received a carrier signal from the remote modem that meets the suitable signal criteria.
> 6. At this point data transfer can began. If the local modem has full-duplex capability, the CTS (Clear to Send) and RTS (Request to Send) signals are held in the asserted state. If the modem has only half-duplex capability, CTS and RTS provide the handshaking necessary for controlling the direction of the data flow. Data is transferred over the RXD and TXD signals.
> 7. When the transfer of data has been completed, the PC disables the DTR signal. The modem follows by inhibiting the DSR and DCD signals. At this point the PC and modem are in the original state described in step number 1. [*In reality either PC might send an AT command to tell the modem to terminated the call.*]

The italics portions are mine.

Another excellent description, from McGraw Hill: [link](http://duinorasp.hansotten.com/uploads/2740_EIA_RS-232-C.pdf).

Here's a diagram:

Red is caller, green is recipient; Bright is DTE (terminals), dark is DCE (modems).

[image]

Comment: While this is likely the best way to answer the question, the DCD signal indicates whether you still receive a carrier, not whether the remote line is hung up. Suppose the remote communication device is an acoustic coupler with a telephone handset on it, you will see DCD drop even if the phone is still off-hook. Depending on the kind of analog phone network, the local device doesn't get a chance to know whether the remote side hung up or not, so relying on DCD is the right thing to do.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher You're right of course, that DCD doesn't tell us the other side has hung up.  However, there isn't any signal that says whether the *far* end is on the call; the local DCE says *we* are on the call (DSR) and we can hear them (DCD), if indeed we can.  I added a sentence that we normally give DCD a timeout before deciding the other end has hung up.  If A DTE sees DCD go down, it should definitely take DTR down to tell the local DCE to hang up.  Especially if you're the originator, paying for the call.

Comment: I added my comment because the question started talking about RI, which indicates that the *far end* is calling us, but there is no complementary "hangup indicator". You are completely correct by focussing on DTR to make sure the call is ended.

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on the details as there may not be one true way of doing it.

But if we are talking about a standard PC and standard telephone line modem, the carrier detect (CD) line will drop in case the call is disconnected.

Also the modem would genrally send textual information to PC, saying "NO CARRIER", if enabled.

Comment: "saying "NO CARRIER" It would, though that's a function of an intelligent Hayes (compatible) modem rather than a function of the RS-232 physical layer. &$(!& NO CARRIER